# The use of error by struct keyword

Tags: c

```
typedef struct error{int warning, error, exception;}error;

main()
{
    error g1;
    g1.error =1;
    printf("%d",g1.error);
}
```

Here is code sample of whose output is 1.

But I need a explanation of how this code is working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the inside of the onion:

```
struct error
{
    int warning, error, exception;
};
```

That defines a struct called `error` with 3 elements: `warning`, `error`, and `exception`.

To use it, you could have replaced the `error g1;` line in your `main` function with `struct error g1;`. Then you wrap that struct definition in a typedef, which essentially tells the compiler that there's a type `error` that's equivalent to `struct error`. The names are all in independent spaces: types, a struct, and elements in that struct. So they don't clash. That said, it's a bit cleaner to write

```
typedef struct
{
    int warning, error, exception;
} error;
```

since it doesn't give the struct 2 names. The first version I gave is also valid; some people prefer to be explicit about their usage of structs.

Answer (score 2):

What is it that you don't understand in this code? `error` is not a reserved word in C, so you are free to use it as a (variable/struct) name.

You defined a `struct` containing 3 `int` fields, instantiated it as a local variable `g1`, assigned 1 to one of its fields, then printed that field on the standard output. If you have any more specific questions, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You defined a struct `error` that has an `int` member named `error`. You defined a typedef (in other words, an alias) for `struct error`, named `error`. You then created an instance of `struct error`, named `g1`, using the typedef name. Then, you assigned the value `1` to the `error` member of the `error` instance `g1`. Finally, you printed the value of `g1.error`.

Struct names and typedef names occupy separate namespaces — they can be the same. In C, you *must* put the keyword `struct` before structs' names:

```
struct S{ /*...*/ };

struct S instance1;
```

But not before typedef names:

```
struct S{ /*...*/ };
typedef struct S S;

S instance2;
```

You can also typedef unions and enums. You can combine a struct definition with a typedef definition:

```
typedef struct S { /* ... */ } S;
```

And you can omit the struct name:

```
typedef struct { /* ... */ } S;
```

In this case, the struct type can only be referred to via the typedef.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty basic use of a typedef struct in c.  I'd recommend you visit [the wikipedia page on structs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29) for a general overview, but in short:

The first line creates a new structure type `struct error` which contains 3 integers: `warning`, `error`, and `exception`.  The typedef acts as an alias renaming the `struct error` to just `error` so you can refer to items of this type by just the short name.

The code inside main then creates a new `error` on the stack, sets its `error` property to 1, and then prints it out.